# How to get in class variable from outside class

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem. how to get a variable from outside class in the class?

```
<?php
    include("Configuration.php");
    $MySql = new MySql();
    class MySql{
        public function Connect(){
            mysql_connect($ip, $login, $password); //error Undefined variable: ip,login,password
        }
        function SelectDatabase(){

        }
    }
?>
```

Configuration.php:

```
<?php
$ip = "localhost";
$db = "website";
$login = "";
$password = "";
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: This isn't related to your original question but please avoid using `mysql_...` Those functions have been deprecated.

Comment: Also: please use the `mysqli` interface - `mysql_connect` and friends are obsolete and will be removed from PHP soon. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: Why don't you just `include` inside the `Connect()` method?

Comment: This is basic syntax question. If you are in process of learning PHP, please read the OOP section in PHP manual.

Comment: Seems a shame/waste to use `mysql_` functions with a class.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** continue down this path. I have no idea what you're doing here, but using `mysql_query` in new code is ridiculous and writing your own ORM, if that's what this is going to end up as, is a complete waste of time. These things are hard to write correctly, especially if you're not intimately familiar with PHP. Before you do any more damage, consider using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that provides all of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [**`global`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), or pass them in as parameters.

```php
public function Connect(){
 global $ip, $login, $password;
```

```php
public function Connect($ip, $login, $password){
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the constructor.

```
   include('Configuration.php');
   $MySql = new MySql($ip, $login, $password);
```

And your MySQL class:

```
class MySql
{

    protected $ip, $login, $password;

    public function __construct($ip, $login, $password)
    {
        $this->ip       = $ip;
        $this->login    = $login;
        $this->password = $password;
    }


    public function Connect()
    {
        mysql_connect($this->ip,
            $this->login,
            $this->password);
    }

    function SelectDatabase(){}

}
```

Just a little tip for your further development. You probably wanna assign your connection to a property in the object, it's just good manners to close it again. It could look something like this:

```
class MySql
{

    protected $ip, $login, $password, $conn;

    public function __construct($ip, $login, $password)
    {
        $this->ip       = $ip;
        $this->login    = $login;
        $this->password = $password;
    }


    public function Connect()
    {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($this->ip,
                                    $this->login,
                                    $this->password);
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
         mysql_close($this->conn);
    }

}
```

And yeah, as several others stated, `mysql_connect()` etc. is deprecated, but I see you're aware.

Comment: I prefer this method to my suggested ones. +1

Comment: After all that work, why not just suggest a `mysqli_` solution instead? (wink) - Once OP gets a notice about `mysql_` functions being deprecated, would need to totally rebuild.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You got a point. But my guess is that, when asking such a basic question, OP is in a learning-state and just kata-coding right now ;) So at the time something goes into production and not just sandbox, he's probably miles away using PDO anyway!

Comment: I'm just trying to save everybody a bit of time. ;)

Comment: He knows a lot, so we better go with `$Lord_knows[]="You try";` - and that concludes our OT-conversation!